# MongoDB - Replacing all records(type:string) which ended with `#viewPageContent` in a url with regex and update

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I have a MongoDB NoSQL database, the name is `baike`, there is a collection named `baike_items` with the following format:

```
id:
title:
baike_id
page_url
text
```

All other fields are fine except the `page_url`. Some of the urls are normal like:

```
'https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%A5%91%E4%B8%B9%E6%97%8F/2390374'
```

But some urls are ended with a string `#viewPageContent`, like:

```
https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%E6%97%8F/11435374#viewPageContent
```

My intention is to write a mongoDB query to remove all the urls' `#viewPageContent` string while keep the rest of the string.

```
https://baike.baidu.hk/item/123#viewPageContent
https://baike.baidu.hk/item/456#viewPageContent
.
.
.
```

to

```
https://baike.baidu.hk/item/123
https://baike.baidu.hk/item/456
.
.
.
```

Any suggestions? thanks.

**update1**
The following python should do it.

```py
db.baike_items.update_many(
  { "page_url": { "$regex": "#viewPageContent"} },
  [{
    "$set": { "page_url": {
      "$replaceOne": { "input": "$page_url", "find": "#viewPageContent", "replacement": "" }
    }}
  }]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old_url = "https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%85%89%E5%AD%B8/61334055#viewPageContent"

new_url = old_url.replace("#viewPageContent", "")
```

```
print(old_url)
>>> https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%85%89%E5%AD%B8/61334055#viewPageContent

print(new_url)
>>> https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%85%89%E5%AD%B8/61334055
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = "https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%85%89%E5%AD%B8/61334055#viewPageContent"
print(re.sub(r"#viewPageContent", '', a))
```

output: `https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%85%89%E5%AD%B8/61334055`

Hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
db.baike_items.update_many(
  { "page_url": { "$regex": "#viewPageContent"} },
  [{
    "$set": { "page_url": {
      "$replaceOne": { "input": "$page_url", "find": "#viewPageContent", "replacement": "" }
    }}
  }]
)
```